# Mysql вместо интерфейса текст

Tags: mysql

При входе по ссылке в базу данных MySQL, вместо интерфейса появляется текст
[image: mysql]

Comment: php интерпретатор не работает. включите.

Comment: Во-первых, php-сайт phpmyadmin не является базой данных и не имеет никакого отношения к базе данных (кроме того, что он умеет подключаться к базе данных). Во-вторых, на веб-сервере просто не включена обработка php, читайте документацию к своему веб-серверу